# To find whether columns are in order or not

Tags: excel, vba

First look at the following snippet-

[image: Excel Example]

In column A, we've material code & in Column D, we've Batch Creation Date. Now what do I want is an output like Column E. (I've putted the True/False manually). So, what is the condition I've done manually to determine True/False? I'm explaining it.

- I first filter the material and take one individual material code.
- Then against this material code I get some batch creation date in column D.
- Then I manually check the dates and if I find the ascending order of the date breaks, I put "False" against that date.

Now what I need to know, how can I accomplish the same thing by formula/vba so when I'll be working with numerous material I don't need to check each material manually.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This would be easier to understand if you can post samples of what you're describing, and what you're trying to do.  See "[mcve]" and "[ask]" for tips on asking questions here.

Comment: I've already attached an image as sample. If you click the hyperlink, you can find the sample, then it would be easier to you to understand the requirement.

Comment: Your process is not clear to me. Perhaps you could start by recording a macro, and then clean up the generated code.

Comment: It is also confusing that in your data, for any given material code, the dates are NOT in ascending order, even though you write you are looking to see if *the ascending order of the date breaks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell `E2` enter the formula:

```
=OR(A3<>A2,D3>=D2)
```

Then drag this formula to populate the remaining rows.

Comment: Thanks Lee Mac! :D It's exactly what I need!